# Ampersand in email subject line appears encoded

Tags: exm

The name of my client's company contains an ampersand, they use `EXM` for an email campaign. The issue they are having is that the ampersand appears as `&amp;`  instead of &

Tries to enter the following in the subject line field of EXM:

Tom & Jerry  
Tom `&amp;` Jerry
Tom `%26` Jerry
Tom `&amp;#38`  Jerry

all render as: Tom `&amp;` Jerry

Any idea?

Comment: Which version of EXM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and it was fixed in version 3.3

Please check the release note of EXM 3.3

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Email%20Experience%20Manager/Email%20Experience%20Manager%2033/Email%20Experience%20Manager%2033%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes

Tokens are encoded in email subject. (75647)

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like our version is older, will update EXM then.

Comment: if you can't update EXM please write the version of EXM to give you a hotfix for the problem